# naming convention in constraint and index

Tags: mysql, sql

Can both index and constraint have the same name and  what is recommended naming convention

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`books` (
 `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `isbn` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `category_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `publisher_id` INT NOT NULL ,
  `year` YEAR NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`) ,
  INDEX `fk_books_category_id` (`category_id` ASC) ,
  INDEX `fk_books_publisher_id` (`publisher_id` ASC) ,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_books_category_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`category_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`categories` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_books_publisher_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`publisher_id` )
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`publishers` (`id` )
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Comment: Index name should be prefixed with idx_

Comment: just a suggestion, to separate the type from the name, you can also use camelCasing but, it will be helpful if you prefix it with idx_

Comment: i didn't get it "separate the type from the name" what is type and what is name

Comment: like if you want to create an index on `category_id` try `idx_category_id` and if you want a foreign constraint try `fk_category_id`

Comment: Mysql workbench creates it in the form fk_category_idx i will stick to that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such standard. Although, in MYSQL  there is no need to give a symbolic name to foreign key constraints. If a name is not given, InnoDB creates a unique name automatically.

Although many programmers prefer to use `idx_` as prefix for index and `fk_` for foreign key.

Comment: is there any harm if both are named same

Comment: you mean idx_ in starting

Comment: There is no harm but it will be confusing for you and also it is not a good practice to  follow!!!

Comment: k will keep them diffrent

Comment: Sure that will make things easier for you!!! :) P.S. If my answer helped you dont forget to accept it as answer!!! ;)

Comment: As you already know KISS i.e., '*K*eep *I*t *S*imple *S*tupid' when ever possible ;)